# How to combine like elements in list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reorganize my list according to its peers.

I have this list:

`['datetime', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PRESS_HPA', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PRESS_HPA']`

and i want to do something like this:

`['datetime', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PRESS_HPA', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PRESS_HPA']`

the element 'datetime' must be the first element in list, but i think i can do this after reordered list

Comment: Any particular rule to sort it by? Format of data (this example only or sth else is allowed)? This is pretty vague.

Comment: You want to sort by the last word ? but that's not enough, please clarify

Comment: What is a peer ? Is ii related to the suffix `_M-` ? Don't forget that without context and if you even don't provide any clue on the logic it'll be difficult to answer.

Comment: it is the last word guys, DVENTO, PREC_MM, PRESS_HPA. but i have more elements and this needs to be done dynamically

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
data = ['datetime', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PREC_MM',
        'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PRESS_HPA', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PRESS_HPA']
data.remove("datetime") # removing datetime as it is the odd one in the list
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x.split("-")[-1])# sorting based on the last element ie. element after '-'
data.insert(0, "datetime") # Inserting the odd element 'datetime' back
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
['datetime', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PRESS_HPA', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PRESS_HPA']
```

Hope this helps. happy Coding :)

Comment: No need to remove the first element - just slice after it. No need to explicitly refer to 'datetime' as you know it's always the first element in the list

Answer (score 0):

If the last "word" is prefixed by hyphen then:

```
indata = ['datetime', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PRESS_HPA', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PRESS_HPA']

print([indata[0]] + sorted(indata[1:], key=lambda e: e.split('-')[-1]))
```

**Output:**

```
['datetime', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-DVENTO', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PREC_MM', 'INMET_BRASILIA_A001_M-PRESS_HPA', 'INMET_CURITIBA_A807_M-PRESS_HPA']
```